# Play Protect doesn’t recognise this app’s developer PlayProtect issue

Tags: apk, google-play-protect

I have created a simple apk in the android studio with targetSdk 33 and  compileSdk 33, but when I install the apk in mobiles Play Protects gives different errors likes:-

=>This application may be harmful
=>This app my be harmful
=>This app was built for an older version of android and doesnt include the latest privacy protection
=>Play Protect doesn’t recognise this app’s developer. App from unknown developers can simetimes be unsafe

When I download an apk from apkpure or fdroid then play protect gives no prompt. I download the source code of the same apk and compiled it with my android studio then again play protects starts giving errors. I also tried to delete my debug.keystore. I also created .pem and .pk8 files with openssl and sign my apk with these files yet play protects not stop giving these here. Please tell me whats going on

I delete debug.keystore
I created .pk8 and .pem files and use signapk.jar to sign the apk file
I also use keytool to create new .keystore file and use apksigner to sign the apk file
I also use uber-apk-signer-1.2.1.jar to sign the apk

Please tell why play protect not gives error when apks are download from fdroid and apkpure (even when these apks are not present in playstore) and it gives weird errors on my simple helloworld apk

Comment: Have you just downloaded the apk from f-droid or also tried to install it? PlayProtect only gets active you you install an app.

Comment: @Robert Yes I downloaded the apk from Fdroid and also install it and play protect gives not prompt. This is the link of apk https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.nicobrailo.pianoli/. When I open the source code of this application in my android studio and build a debugable apk play protect then gives prompt of "This app may be harmful" for my debugable apk.